# From template to vm creation, hostname doesnt change

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, rhel

I created a VM from RHEL ISO Fle, and followed some steps to cleanup nic details and also inserted a systemd script to create machine id. Converted VM to template, However when i spin a new VM with new hostname via template, it has same Hostname as template. Can you please direct what i missed here, I went through lot of documents found online nothing helped me out. New to VMware world.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vSphere handles the template creation at the Virtual Machine level, by default. Therefore, anything internal to the VM is not modified during the deployment of a template.

There is a way to change that through the usage of Guest Customizations. This will allow you you to change several internal properties of the VM, including the guest OS' hostname. More info: [Create a Customization Specification for Linux](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-9A5093A5-C54F-4502-941B-3F9C0F573A39.htmlhttps://)